# Does IBM Worklight support Android's ProGuard?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

I wanted to obfuscate the JavaScript source code of worklight/Cordova in an IBM Worklight hybrid apps. After testing in my actual apps, the apps went full black screen after launch, not even the splash screen was displayed. I've wait more than 10 minutes and it doesn't seems to load anything.

So I am suspecting that my apps may not work well with ProGuard and therefore I started a new worklight application with only Android environment and a Hello world message, the Apps run perfectly before the ProGuard and it went full black screen right after I turn on the ProGuard
There is some warning during the ProGuard compilation and I had to specify -dontwarn in the ProGuard setting to compile it successfully.

Have heard from the support that we could run ProGuard on the worklight, but can't find any demonstration and working example anywhere.

Is Worklight not compatible with ProGuard?

Comment: use https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: starting MobileFirst 7.0 there is official support for ProGuard.

---

IBM Worklight currently does **not** support [Android's ProGuard feature](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

As an alternative, you can follow the instructions in the following IBM Worklight blog post, on how to "obfuscate" your application's JavaScript:

- [Obfuscating JavaScript code in Worklight applications](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/obfuscating_javascript_code?lang=en)

I would read carefully the note mentioned in the blog post:

> ... it is very important to understand that code obfuscation, especially
>   in JavaScript, is a relatively weak security measure. Most modern web
>   debugging tools are smart enough to "prettify" the obfuscated code
>   reverting it to a much more readable (however still not original)
>   format.

Comment: Just to clarify, IBM Worklight does not support ProGuard, or it does not support ALL obfuscation tools out there?

Comment: I don't know what are "ALL obfuscation tools out there", so I cannot comment on that, obviously. Can you? ... Pertinent to this question, IBM Worklight does not currently support Android ProGuard.

Comment: I'm asking if Worklight does not support any sort obfuscation tools due to its framework, or it is only an issue with ProGuard.

Comment: Again, different tools provide different abilities. I don't know. The blog post suggests a way to obfuscate JS code. ProGuard likely does not work due to a bug. If you'd like ProGuard support, please send a feature request, here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html